# Python: I'm getting an error saying that the list index in out of range, when isn't

Tags: python

I'm making a hangman game using python and I am trying to make a leader board system. It's supposed to add the player's inputted name to a *.txt* file along with how many guesses it took them to find the word. There is a *.txt* file for every word, and I am trying to print out the top three results (which I will do after this question is answered, so spare yourself the time and don't try to help with that) but whenever I try to even store the two parts of their score (name and guesses, split with a dash between them) I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Gummi
>   Bear\Desktop\ALL 
>   FOLDERS\Useful\Coding\Python\Other\Videos\Hangman_Hangman.py", line 200, in < module >
>       main() File "C:\Users\Gummi Bear\Desktop\ALL  FOLDERS\Useful\Coding\Python\Other\Videos\Hangman_Hangman.py", line
>   195, in main
>       tries = x[1] IndexError: list index out of range

(sorry for the bad indentation in that error quote)

The bit of code that is failing is this:

```
name = input ("Please enter your name: ")
f = open(word+".txt", "a+")
f.write ("\n" + name + "-" + str(len(guesses)))
f = open (word+".txt", "r")
file = f.read()
for line in file:
    x = line.split("-")
    name = x[0]
    tries = x[1]
    print (name + "----" + tries)
```

If anyone can help, please do: I've checked a lot of other similar questions and none of them solve my specific problem. Thanks!

Comment: Format error as code, not quote. Use the edit button below your question.

Comment: What do you see when you `print(x)` on the line after you split it? This is likely a list with less than 2 elements.

Comment: Have you tried printing the line that fails?  What if the line has no `'-'`?

Comment: following up on @byxor 's comment, can you show us the format of the data you are applying split to?

Comment: Any time you think the error message is wrong, you are wrong. The likelihood of you uncovering a genuine bug in a program as mature as Python at this stage in your career is small. Always debug, check your inputs, and trace where they came from.

Comment: Also don't forget to close `f`!  Use the `with open(...) as f:` syntax to make sure the file is automatically closed at the end of the block.

Comment: @byxor, it gives me ["*name*", "*score*\n"] except name* and *score* are replaced with their actual values, nothing I can see wrong, unless that is a problem.

Comment: and @SilverNitrateIon, the format of the data is implied in the question and code but the format goes like this:   *name*-*score*

Comment: @candybar521 Explicit is better than implicit, here at SO we try to be as clear as possible. What is clear to you may not be clear to everyone. Also please see the community [How To Ask A Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) document!